# Accurate long polling example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, long-polling

I've made an function that should do an long polling and fetch live data that is being "pushed" to me. Right now I'm testing against an json object that is formatted in the way that it will look once I receive the data. It seems as it is working accurate so far. I was merely wondering what you think about it? Would you refactor it somehow or do it entirely in another way?

```
var url = '../../path_to_script/respondents.json';

function fetchData() {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        //parseData(data);
        setTimeout(function () { fetchData() }, 5000);
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        setTimeout(function () { fetchData() }, 5000)
    }

 });

}
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do some changes

- Change `method` to `type`, `method` isn't a valid parameter for `$.ajax`. This is an error
- Remove `contentType`, with `dataType: 'json'` is enough to have those values
- Do something when there's an error. Use the error parameters if you need them. For example:

.

```
error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
  alert("There was an error processing your request.\nPlease try again.\nStatus: " + status);
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: thanks for the input. Was also thinking that contentType was maybe a bit redundant. Good idea too use the error parameters, this I will do. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This works like expected. Since you've wisely choosen to fire a `setTimeout` once the request returned, there can't be "overlapping" requests. That is a good thing.

Anyway, you could use jQuerys "new" deferred ajax objects which is probably a little bit more convinient.

```
(function _poll() {
    $.getJSON( url ).always(function( data ) {
        console.log( data );
        _poll();
    });
}());
```

*Note*: `.always()` is brandnew (jQuery 1.6).

**Edit**

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rjgwW/6/

Comment: Ok, interesting, I'm clearly not that updated on jQuery 1.6. One thing though, the setTimeout, would you keep on doing that the same way?

Comment: I tried your example but I cant really get it to work. Could you maybe post an example how it would look to you? Thanks

Comment: @Tim: I updated the answer with an example link. That example also contains a `setTimeout` again to delay requests.

Comment: Cheers, although it gives me an error: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<XMLHttpRequest> has no method 'always'
_polllongPoll.js:4
(anonymous function). I might add that I have included jQuery 1.6

Answer (score 2):

I suggest changing the events to:

```
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
},
complete: function () {
    setTimeout(function () { fetchData() }, 5000)
}
```

The complete event is always called after success and error. This way you will only have the setTimeout line once, which is better.